# What is the German equivalent of the English phrase "Fuck me"?

Tags: english-to-german

In English I say "fuck me" a lot to show annoyance with myself.  So, I'm not trying to say "fuck-me" in the sexual way such as "fuck-me" boots etc.  Is there a way to say this in the German used in Berlin?

Edit:  I say "fuck me" in English to myself when I realize I have been screwed by someone or something and I have helped the someone or something screw myself.  This is the context I'm looking for so I'm not looking a phrase to call myself directly "a fool"  or something.

Edit:  Do the Viennese have an appropriate equivalent if the Berliners do not?

Comment: In parts of Germany, a similarly vulgar expression addressed to no one in particular and used to give vent to momentary frustration is _Leck mich doch_, but I am not sure how common that is in Berlin. (The two words following this phrase are implied but not spoken. It's a famous (or infamous) line spoken by Ritter Götz von Berlichingen in Goethe's eponymous play and is sometimes represented by its acronym LMAA.)

Comment: @EugeneSeidel I totally agree, just one minor tidbit: In Goethe's Götz it wasn't LMAA, but rather LMIA ("er kann mich im Arsche lecken") Why don't you put your comment in an answer, so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @bouscher I am happy for someone else to use my comment and collect the points :)

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Entweder falsche Bescheidenheit oder Sie gehen umsichtig mit Ihrem Renommee um ;-)

Comment: I never heard *Leck mich doch* out of annoyance about oneself, but only about others, where it is rather insulting – basically it is what you say to end a heated argument and, at the same time, tell your opponent that he really pissed you off. Therefore I strongly recommend not to use it to express self-annoyance.

Comment: Come to think of it, my suggestion is not a 100 percent fit. (Although I am puzzled that Wurzel has heard it spoken only to others.) Here is where I would say it: my magnetic-tipped screwdriver loses the tiny philips screw which drops into the bowels of the computer I am fixing, getting wedged under the motherboard. Cursing gives vent to my frustration at the unfairness of life... or _die Tücke des Objekts_ / Murphy's law. At the same time, however, I am aware that it's still my fault for not being more careful... so my suggestion is not really wrong, either.

Comment: Would **Fick mich** fit in this context, or ever for that matter?

Comment: @ Eugene:  What do mean by "this phrase are implied but not spoken"?  Which two words aren't spoken?  Lost. :-(

Comment: How come some answers were deleted?  I read here yesterday someone wrote "meine fresse" or something?

Comment: Please don't put a space between the @ and the name if you want notification to work. See this [mini monograph](http://forum.dnn-online.de/phrasenpharao-schrammses-i-erklaert/9751-leck-mich-doch-am-arsch.html) on DNN Online, it explains what "AA" in the acronym LMAA stands for and gives some historical background. In any case we've already heard from a Berliner that they don't typically say it there in such a context, so as far as I'm concerned _Leck mich doch_ is not the right answer to your question.

Comment: @Dustin In the English language, coarse talk (or vulgar language, the two are not exactly the same) is mostly grounded in sexual function. But in German, it is mostly centered around bowel movements. So your proposal would not fit, I'm afraid.

Comment: @verve: I deleted my answer because it is not a 100% match, and the answer you have below is probably the best you can get for Berlin ;)

Answer (score 7):

I’m from Berlin, I’m annoyed with myself a lot, and to show that I use:

> Ick Idiot!

or

> Mann, ick Idiot!

or to really elaborate on the issue:

> Mann, ick bin doch ein seltendaemlicher Idiot.

“Leck mich am Arsch” in that sense is almost never used here.

Comment: also have a look at http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=1074270&idForum=2&lang=de&lp=ende for a supra-regional solution.

Comment: "I'm an idiot" doesn't quiote capture the essence of "Fuck me". It's more of a passive-aggressive exclamation like "so it's my fault or what?"

Comment: @hroptatyr:  Hmm...calling myself an idiot is what I'm was looking for but more like I got screwed by something and I helped get myself screwed.

Comment: @verve try this one: "ich könnte mich in den Hintern treten!"

Answer (score 5):

I would translate it to: "Ich könnt' mich in den Hintern treten!" oder: "Ich könnte *mir* in den Hintern beißen!"

I hear the last one quite often and use it myself although normally you would have to use *mich* instead of *mir* to be grammatically correct. This might be due to regional differences.

Comment: "Ich könnt' mir den Arsch beißen" fits perhaps better to "fuck me".

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your edit about Vienna: I'd say there are a few options:

Ah, ich bin so ein Trottel heute.

which you can freely shorten to:

- Ah, ich bin so ein Trottel
- Ah, i bin a so a Trottel
- Ah, bin i a Trottel
- Ah, so a Trottel (careful, might also mean someone who is not yourself)

(Instead of Trottel, feel free to insert other similar words like Depp, Koffer, Vollkoffer, Mongo (yeah, I know that this one really should not be used like that, but it is still quite common), Angrennter, Dodel, Idiot, ...)

In some cases you might also use:
Ich könnt' ma in Orsch beißen.

However, this one is a little bit more tricky as it needs to refer to some sort of regret eg. Ich könnt ma in Orsch beißen, dass ich ma damals keine Bitcoin 'kauft hab'.

If it is something passive you might also use: Da hab ich mich aber gscheid einereiten lassen. (more like "yeah, they kinda fucked me over - in a very slow and non-obvious way")

Personally, I know the expression "Fuck me!" more in a way of surprise. Like in "Fuck me! Her birthday is already today, not next week?!" Which I would translate to "Leck (mi' do' am) Orsch!"

Comment: In your list of "similar words like Depp" is a noticeable and very Viennese gap: "Wappler" and "Weh" (as in the Worried Men Skiffle Groups classic "Wauns'd a Weh brauchst, ruafst mi aun."). Also, instead of "Leck Oasch" there is also "(I) Scheiß' mi aun!"

Comment: You are totally right, how could I forget Wappler?! However, "I bin a so a Weh" - never heard anyone use it that way. I also agree on your "(I) scheiß' mi aun!" - maybe even than Leck Orsch ...

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you'd use a direct translation of the English phrase in Germany: "Ich bin / wurde gefickt" or when emphasizing that you "opened your backdoor": "Ich hab mich ficken lassen".

It will be considered vulgar in some circles, but it is broadly accepted as an expression of great negativeness amongst younger people.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for resurrecting a zombie question, but I don't know that it's even possible to generically translate this phrase. "f@#k" is an extremely versatile word (one episode of **The Wire**'s first season sports an extended dialog using nothing but), and "f@#k me" can have wildly different meanings depending on exactly how and when you say it. Applicable German equivalents are e.g. *Verdammt nochmal*, *Ich Idiot*, or *Da stecke ich ja schön in der Sch***e, or *Du kommst mir gerade richtig*, and so on and on.

Answer (score 0):

Derartige Wendungen sind der deutschen Umgangssprache eher fremd. Transitive Wendungen finden sich allenfalls mit tatsächlich persönlichem Bezug, etwa im Ausdruck von Ablehnung oder der Aufforderung zu gehen. Bemerkenswerter Weise sind diese Bedeutungen auch der englischen Wendung nicht fremd und insbesondere in lateinisch 2Sg.imp. *fugit* "flieh" zu erkennen.

Entsprechende Ausdrucksweisen sind zu Deutsch eher der Fäkalsprache zu entnehmen.

Anstelle der Personalpronomina sind Indefinitpronomen *man*, *ey* und gleichfalls Modalpartikel *jetzt, man*, Berliner Mundart *wa*, Oberdeutsch *oh* zur Intensivierung des Ausdrucks zu gebrauchen.

Eine Definitive Antwort kann nicht gegeben werden, da die Wortwahl stark vom sozialen Hintergrund, sowie dem Familiolekt, und dementgegen vom steten Wandel der Jugendsprache einschließlich Lehnworten geprägt ist (zum Zeitpunkt der Fragestellung 2013 noch *tschau, tschü* "bye" nach Türkisch *çüş* "wait", heute eher *Dicka* bzw. *bro* quasi als Anrede in jeglichem Sinne, zwischendurch auch mal Arabisch *hamdula* "So will Gott", *wala* "Bei Gott, für Wahr; Echt jetzt?" und auch immer wieder Denglisch). Zudem hängt die Bedeutung von der Betonung ab. Daher kann man es einfach bei *Ei!* oder ähnlichem belassen und die Ton-Kontur aus der Englischen Wendung übernehmen. Vergleiche dazu *ai!* aus den Romanischen Sprachen, d.h. etwa "au!", "oh!" und ist vermutlich mit "Au weia!" bzw. Yiddish "Oy vey!" verwandt.

Besonders süß ist übrigens *Scheibenkleister* bzw. nach Matt Groenings *Die Simpsons" auch ***Scheibenhonig*** (*sliced honey*, minced oath for *Schei...*). Die übliche unverschleierte Form wird oft mit Anrede gebraucht, "$faecēs, Bernd" (Zangendeutsch) oder idiomatisch "$faecēs man", "Ey, mit diese $faecēs immer", "Scheiße eh" (vgl. Dänisch, Mittelenglisch, Norse [æ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A6) oder Altenglisch [ǣ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C7%A3#Old_English)). Das ist witzig weil Kaka pfui ist und der Ausdruck doch rein gar nix mit [faecēs](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/faec%C4%93s) zu tun hat – vgl. En. [skid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skid), [skidaddle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skidaddle), De. ''scheiden'', wie L. *fugō*. q.e.d.